# Feed back prophet forecast to the dataset - Python

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

Let's assume I trained Prophet's mode:

```
weekly.columns = ['y', 'ds']# change column names so that Prophet likes them
m = Prophet(growth = "linear", mcmc_samples = 0,
            holidays=holidays, holidays_prior_scale=1,
            seasonality_mode = "multiplicative",
            seasonality_prior_scale = 10,
            changepoint_prior_scale=1, 
            #n_changepoints = 5,
            yearly_seasonality=False, 
            weekly_seasonality=False, 
            daily_seasonality=False, interval_width =0.95).fit(weekly)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq='W')
fcst = m.predict(future)
```

And then, did the forecast for the next week using. So the forecast contains the huge list of different attributes. What will be a better way to get predictions alongside the actuals?

```
#making a forecast
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods = 1, freq = 'w')
forecast = m.predict(future)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()

forecast['actuals'] = weekly['y']?
```

Comment: What is `Prophet` ? What is `make_future_dataset` ? What is the general context ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was explicit with my heading. Prophet is a library that allows doing time-series forecast, developed by FB.